# jquery html/string manipulation

Tags: jquery, string

Is it possible to use `$(someSelector).html('some string');` and not replace the content of this selector but add the `'some string'` at the beginning of the content?

Also after I add it is it possible to remove the `'some string'` from the "someSelector" html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q #1: [**`jQuery.prepend()`**](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) accepts an HTML string.

Q #2: Yes. One possible option is by using the native `.replace()` method.

Comment: Any idea why I wouldn't have replace method?

Comment: It's a native JS method (not jQuery). See **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)**. It must be called on a string. I'm betting you are trying to do `$(someSelector).replace()`?

Comment: so something like this should work? `var html = $('.items-large').html();
    html.toString().replace("<div class='width-specifier-large'><img src=" + url + " alt='@Model.ProductName'/> onerror='onImgErrorSmall(this)'</div> ", '');` and then `$('.items-large').html("<div class='width-specifier-large'><img src=" + url + " alt='@Model.ProductName'/> onerror='onImgErrorSmall(this)'</div> " + html);`

Comment: Please post a link to a pastebin of that. Comments are not good for large blocks of code.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.prepend()` -> http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Answer (score 1):

You could either get the current HTML of the element, prepend the string, and then change the HTML, or you could use .prepend().

```
$("#me").prepend("Some string.");
```

Answer (score 1):

to add:

```
$(someSelector).prepend('foo');
```

to remove:

```
$(someSelector).html($(someSelector).html().replace('foo',''));
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `prepend` [ http://api.jquery.com/prepend/ ] with an element (`span` for example)

```
$(someSelector).prepend('<span id="somethingunique">some string</span>');
```

So you could remove later

```
$("#somethingunique").remove();
```

Will this work for you?

Comment: I have to remove some html from a class. This will not work, but thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use .prepend('some string').

Which 'some string' do you want to then remove?

Comment: good point, I guess first I should remove it, and then I should prepend the html.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
var content = $(someSelector).html(); 
var newContent = 'some string' + content;
$(someSelector).html(newContent);
```